# Azure Web API Project Recommended data connection settings using Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-api-apps, azure-sql-database

I'm creating an Azure Web API that is connecting to an Azure SQL database.  I was about to add the model classes using the Entity Data Model Wizard in Visual Studio when it asks what to do with the connection settings.  I do not know what to do from here.

What is the recommended settings I should enter for this page?

I know that the API app settings from the Azure portal contain the connection settings to my database (From the Web app > Settings > Application Settings > Connection String)

Am I supposed to exclude the sensitive data, and somehow reference the connection string name from Azure portal?

And what about the last checkbox - am I supposed to save the connection data to WebConfig?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security risk in this dialog means the connection string will be put in *source code* generated by the wizard. Some folks upload their sources to public repository such as GitHub, and it can cause password exposure.

But what about `Web.config`?

Web.config is dedicated file so that easily be excluded by `.gitignore` setting.

In short, your screenshot setting is fine to go and please check Web.Config is well ignored when you upload your code to public repository.

Commonly, ASP.NET developers use [SlowCheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) plugin which gives separate `Web.Debug.Config` and `Web.Release.Config` files and makes `Web.Config` output along with build configuration.

**=EDIT=**

For deeper understanding and implementation, please read http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure

If you publish your ASP.NET to Azure WebApp, Azure portal gives handy UI to configure in settings. It overrides your `Web.Config` values. I recommend to use it.

Check out the documentation:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/

You may click Restart button at WebApp after set it up.

Comment: What if I chose to exclude the sensitive information from the source code and web config?  Is there a way for the api to reference the connection settings in Azure at runtime? Or do I always have to put those in a separate release version that contains connection settings?